# Lenovo z570 WiFi not connecting to dual band router but works well with old single band router and a WiFi device

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

Initially I was using Single Band 2.4GHz router, my Laptop Wi-Fi was connecting to it properly and was working smoothly. Recently I switched to dual band router (5GHz and 2.4GHz)

With Dual band router the laptop Wi-Fi shows only 2.4GHz signal (that’s fine) but when I am trying to connect, it every time says:

> “Not able to Connect”

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the Wi-Fi drivers but it doesn’t help. FWIW, the laptop connects without issue to mobile hotspot. Other laptops(Dell Latitude 3400 and Lenovo G50-80 with Windows 10) do connect to the new dual band router without any issue

Laptop Specifications:

- **OS**: Windows 7 Ultimate
- **Model**: Lenovo z570
- **Wi-Fi Driver**: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Adapter

Router Details:

- **Old Router**: TP-Link TL-WR841N 300Mbps
- **New Router**: Syrotech SY-GPON-4020-WADONT 1200 Mbps Wireless Router  (White, Dual Band)

Comment: Please edited your question: What is the make and model of the old router that works and the new router that doesn’t work?